# Having trouble creating a Singleton AngularJS Service

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a [Single AngularJS service](http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/03/how-to-create-singleton-angularjs-services-in-4-different-ways/) via the 4th method.  My service looks like...

```
provider('SocketService', {
    socket: null,

    // methods used within the config() of a module
    connect: function(url) {
        if (this.socket == null)
            this.socket = portal.open('ws://production.local/socket/'+url);
    },

    // --------- Public methods for handling this socket -------------------------
    $get: function() {
        return {
            getSocket: function() {
                return this.socket;
            },
            on: function (event, handler) {
                if (this.socket == null)
                    console.error('Unable to call .on() - Socket is not connected');

                //if no handler is provided, "event" is an object of handlers...
                if (handler == null)
                    return this.socket.on(event);

                return this.socket.on(event, handler);
            },
            close: function () {
                return this.socket.close();
            }
        };
    }
});
```

`this.socket` continues to be `null` within the $get method.  My controller is initializing the socket as expected...

```
config(['$routeProvider', 'SocketServiceProvider', function($routeProvider, SocketServiceProvider) {
    //only initialize the socket when a URL in this route is accessed...
    function initSocket() { SocketServiceProvider.connect('workstation/approval'); console.log('connected'); }

    /* URL mappings */
    $routeProvider.
        when('/approval', {templateUrl: '/partials/loading.htm',   controller: 'ApprovalCtrl',  resolve: {socketInitializer: initSocket}}).
        when('/approval/dashboard', {templateUrl: '/partials/approval/dashboard.htm',   controller: 'ApprovalCtrl',  resolve: {socketInitializer: initSocket}})
}]).

controller('ApprovalCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', 'WorkflowProcessService', 'WorkstationService', 'SocketService', 'socketUrl', '$location', function ($scope, $cookieStore, WorkflowProcessService, WorkstationService, SocketService, socketUrl, $location) {
    /* Handle socket events coming from the server */
    console.log(SocketService.getSocket()); //returns null
    SocketService.on({
        open: function () {
            $scope.initializing.message = "Loading dashboard...";
            $scope.showDashboard();
        },
        close: function (reason) {
            $scope.initializing.status = true;
            $scope.initializing.message = "Connection lost.  Reconnecting...";
            console.log(reason);
        },
        updateQueueSize: function (r) {
            console.log(r);
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: If you need a global object (which is what a singleton is), why not simply attach an instance of it to the `$rootScope`? That way you are sure what instance you are accessing and won't have to work around Angular's service implementation.

Comment: @Laurent - That's a great thought!  I'm looking at ways to inject the `$rootScope` into the service.  Can't get it to work yet, but still investigating...

Comment: @Laurent - Got it working... can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: ok done, glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a global object (which is what a singleton is), why not simply attach an instance of it to the `$rootScope`?

That way you are sure what instance you are accessing, and won't have to work around Angular's service implementation.